# How do I pose an armorstand in my hand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to be able to pose the armor stand, but so its still in the item form, so when I place it its ready posed, and don't say 'You cant` Because you can. I've seen it before, I have an item in my possession, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Maybe ask the person who showed you you so obviously can.

Answer (score 0):

### This cannot be done in Vanilla Minecraft, so this was likely achieved through a mod.

The only way to achieve posing in Vanilla Minecraft is through commands, to summon an armor stand with the specific command(s) used to pose the armour stand. Online tools like [this one](https://haselkern.github.io/Minecraft-ArmorStand/) makes the command generation simple and easy, but this is the only way to pose your armour stands, without using mods.

As you have stated, you have an "item" that you don't know how to use, which is likely from that mod. If you find the page online for the mod, you'll likely get better luck getting instructions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EntityTag** to specify properties which will be applied to the entity once it spawns. Example: `/give @s minecraft:armor_stand{EntityTag:{ShowArms:1b,Pose:{RightArm:[0f,0f,126f]}}}`